# How to install MiniSom package in Python

Tags: python, som

Does anyone know how to install MiniSom package (or any other Self Organizing Map package) in Python?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

1- Download minisom.py from the below link:
https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom/blob/master/minisom.py

2- Place the file in your working directory

3- in your python program which you want to use minisim enter:
   from minisom import MiniSom

Comment: This helped. But why does pip install minisom is not enough I wonder?

Answer (score 2):

See https://pypkg.com/pypi/minisom/

> To install `MiniSom`, enter the following at the terminal:

```
pip install minisom
```

Comment: Using pip with an activated Anaconda environment you don't need to include the source code in your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the PyMVPA package contains [self-organising maps](http://www.pymvpa.org/examples/som.html) functions. You can find [detailed installation instructions](http://www.pymvpa.org/installation.html) on their website.

Alternatively if you wish to use MiniSOM you can download it from [github](https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom) where [installation instructions](https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom#installation) are included.

Answer (score 0):

Command To install MiniSom:

```
pip install minisom (terminal)
!pip install minisom (google colab)
```